# Manipulating a pandas dataframe to a desired output

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have attempted different methods and have yet to reach a solution.

The question is: how do I convert cues, directions, thresholds, exitsinto a hierarchical JSON structure to be used for a D3 visualization? There are an unknown number of levels, so it has to be dynamic.

I have a dataframe with five columns and 8 rows, each row corresponds to one tree in my case:

```
    tree       cues                        directions   thresholds   exits
     1   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;1;0.5
     2   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;1;0.5
     3   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;0;0.5
     4   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;0;0.5
     5   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;1;0;0.5
     6   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;0;0.5 
     7   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;1;0.5
     8   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;0;0;0.5
```

**Desired Output Snapshot (example: 1st row):**

```
  "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
  "directions": ">",
  "thresholds": "126",
  "exits": "1",
  "children": [
    {
      "cues": "Age",
      "directions": ">",
      "thresholds": "29",
      "exits": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "cues": "BMI",
          "directions": ">",
          "thresholds": "29.7",
          "exits": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "cues": "TimesPregnant",
              "directions": ">",
              "thresholds": "6",
              "exits": "0.5",
              "children": [
                {
                  "cues": "True",
                },
                {
                  "cues": "False"
                }
              ]
```

for the last node in the tree always true and false are given as children, (hence the 0.5 in exits columns)

**EDIT** The desired if exits==1 then first 'True' and the 'cue' else the 'cue' and 'False'

```
{
    "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
    "directions": ">",
    "thresholds": "126",
    "exits": "1",
    "children": [
      {
        "cues": "True",
      },
      {
        "cues": "Age",
        "directions": ">",
        "thresholds": "29",
        "exits": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "cues": "BMI",
            "directions": ">",
            "thresholds": "29.7",
            "exits": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "cues": "True",
              },
              {
                "cues": "TimesPregnant",
                "directions": ">",
                "thresholds": "6",
                "exits": "0.5",
                "children":[
                  {
                    "cues": "True"
                  },
                  {
                    "cues": "False"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cues": "False"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a row of your DataFrame (which is a Series whose indices are your column names), this functions will extract a tree like you've shown:

```py
>>> def row_to_tree(row):
...     out = {}
...     pos = [out]
...     for cues, directions, thresholds, exits in zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(";"), row[["cues", "directions", "thresholds", "exits"]].values)):
...             pos = pos[0]
...             pos["cues"] = cues
...             pos["directions"] = directions
...             pos["thresholds"] = thresholds
...             pos["exits"] = exits
...             pos["children"] = [{"cues":True}]
...             pos = pos["children"]
...     pos.append({"cues": False})
...     return out
```

This works by taking the sequence of strings in your row `row[["cues", "directions", "thresholds", "exits"]].values`, and splitting each string at the ";".  This is accomplished by mapping the function `lambda x: x.split(";")` to each string.  This results in a list where each element is a list from one of your columns (e.g. the first list is the list of cues from that row).  Then, zipping these lists is sort of like taking the transpose of that 2-D list.  Then, we iterate over the values, adding them to a dictionary, and finally adding a new dictionary for the children.

Then, you simply need to apply this function to each row to give you your trees:

```py
>>> trees = [row_to_tree(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]
>>> print(json.dumps(trees[0], indent=2))
{
  "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
  "directions": ">",
  "thresholds": "126",
  "exits": "1",
  "children": [
    {
      "cues": "Age",
      "directions": ">",
      "thresholds": "29",
      "exits": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "cues": "BMI",
          "directions": ">",
          "thresholds": "29.7",
          "exits": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "cues": "TimesPregnant",
              "directions": ">",
              "thresholds": "6",
              "exits": "0.5",
              "children": [
                {
                  "cues": true
                },
                {
                  "cues": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I want now when I add the children I want to do an if there if the exits==1 first add True and then the child and if it's not then first add the child and then add False. Can I achieve this in this loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're asking. What do you want the "children" to look like in each case?

Comment: the parent i.e. 'PLC2hrOGTT' should have "cues": True and then "cues": "Age" because "exits": is "1" in 'PLC2hrOGTT'. I think I managed to explain, if otherwise pls let me know.